# Laravel Vue Component not being shown

Tags: laravel, components, show, vuejs2

I'm stucked with this code. I can't make it work, and i don't get any errors. Which might mean that i need an aditional dependency? It's simply not showing. Please help me. Thanks.

app.js - file

```
Vue.component('message', require('./components/Message.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Message.vue - file

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Message</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm the component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ready () {
            console.log('Component ready')
        }
    }
</script>
```

home.blade.php - file

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
    <h3>Welcome to Site</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="app">
            <message></message>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: Do you have vue dev tools? You can check to see if the root instance has been created. Also if you are using vue 2 the`ready` method has depreciated, you should use `mounted` or other lifecycle methods.

Comment: How will i update vue js to 2 with composer?

Comment: I have Vue 2.1.0, but still nto showing anything. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also need to clear browser cache when working with frontend. On mac this is `command + shift + R`. Also make sure you did run `gulp` to compile your js file.

Also make sure you included compiled js file to your layout template before `</body>`:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the .default from the line

```
Vue.component('message', require('./components/Message.vue').default);
```